# ec2 waitfor timesout after 2 minutes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function that checks the instance status but it timesout. I have set timeout to 2 minutes. The role has all the permissions on EC2.

```
    ec2.waitFor('instanceRunning', {InstanceIds: ['someinstanceid'], DryRun:true}, function(err, data) {
      if (err)
      {
            console.log(err);
            context.fail(err);
      }
      else
      {
            console.log(data);
            context.succeed(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: The statements: "I have set timeout to 2 minutes" and "timesout after 2 minutes" sounds like this is behaving as expected. What exactly is the question? What are you expecting to happen differently?

Comment: I am expecting it to complete waitFor call and return the value rather than timing out.

Comment: Then you might need to wait longer than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

*To anyone that came here riding on google:*

It is possible to configure the behavior of `waitFor` like this:

```
let params = {
    InstanceIds: ["i-1234567890"],
    //Waiter configuration
    $waiter: {
        maxAttempts : 1000,
        delay: 10
    }
};

EC2.waitFor("instanceRunning", params, function(error, data){
    /***/
}.bind(this));
```

Here I configured check delay for 10 seconds, at max 1000 attempts, that is like 166 min.

Note that all `maxAttempts` need to fail so you know that instance actually failed to start, so you probably want to use this carefully.